# Getting last X fields from a specific line in a CSV file using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to get as bash variable list of users which are in my csv file. Problem is that number of users is random and can be from 1-5.

Example CSV file:

```
"record1_data1","record1_data2","record1_data3","user1","user2"
"record2_data1","record2_data2","record2_data3","user1","user2","user3","user4"
"record3_data1","record3_data2","record3_data3","user1"
```

I would like to get something like

```
list_of_users="cat file.csv | grep "record2_data2" | <something> "
echo $list_of_users
user1,user2,user3,user4
```

I'm trying this:

```
cat file.csv | grep "record2_data2" |  awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{print $4,$5,$6,$7,$8 }' | sed 's/"//g'
```

My result is:

```
user2,user3,user4,,
```

Question:
How to remove all "," from the end of my result? Sometimes it is just one but sometimes can be `user1,,,,`
Can I do it in better way? Users always starts after 3rd column in my file.

Comment: I'm trying to get X last records starting from 3 but ending at 4-9. In my case they are users but it doesn't really mater. I would like to be able to get  this list for one line. 
Let's say I would like to get users only for "record2_data2".

Comment: Last X *fields* might be a better way of saying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what your code seems to be trying to do (print the users for a given string `record2_data2` which only exists in the 2nd field):

```
$ awk -F',' '{gsub(/"/,"")} $2=="record2_data2"{sub(/([^,]*,){3}/,""); print}' file.csv
user1,user2,user3,user4
```

but I don't see how that's related to your question subject of `Getting last X records from CSV file using bash` so idk if it's what you really want or not.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Sorry if I wasn't enough precise in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a bash array, and join it into a CSV string when needed:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
readarray -t listofusers < <(cut -d, -f4- file.csv | tr -d '"' | tr ',' $'\n' | sort -u))
IFS=,
printf "%s\n" "${listofusers[*]}"
```

`cut -d, -f4- file.csv | tr -d '"' | tr ',' $'\n' | sort -u` is the important bit - it first only prints out the fourth and following fields of the CSV input file, removes quotes, turns commas into newlines, and then sorts the resulting usernames, removing duplicates. That output is then read into an array with the `readarray` builtin, and you can manipulate it and the individual elements however you need.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `sed` solution, let `file.csv` content be

```
"record1_data1","record1_data2","record1_data3","user1","user2"
"record2_data1","record2_data2","record2_data3","user1","user2","user3","user4"
"record3_data1","record3_data2","record3_data3","user1"
```

then

```
sed -n -e 's/"//g' -e '/record2_data/ s/[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,// p' file.csv
```

gives output

```
user1,user2,user3,user4
```

Explanation: `-n` turns off automatic printing, expressions meaning is as follow: 1st substitute globally `"` using empty string i.e. delete them, 2nd for line containing `record2_data` substitute (`s`) everything up to and including 3rd `,` with empty string i.e. delete it and print (`p`) such changed line.

(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F',' '
  /record2_data2/{
     for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) o=sprintf("%s%s,",o,$i); 
     gsub(/"|,$/,"",o); 
     print o
}' file.csv

user1,user2,user3,user4
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/record2_data/!d;s/"([^"]*)"(,)?/\1\2/4g;s///g' file
```

Delete all records except for that containing `record2_data`.

Remove double quotes from the fourth field onward.

Remove any double quoted fields.